# Как определить внедрение пользователем постороннего скрипта на сайт?

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-программирование

Можно ли как-то определить, когда в тело страницы сайта внедряется посторонний скрипт на стороне пользователя - его браузерным расширением, к примеру. Либо антивирусом.

Можно ли это узнать с помощью JS функции, размещенной в теле страницы? Буду благодарен за примеры.

Answer (score 0):

Можно отслеживать количество подключенных скриптов (ну и их `src`) через `document.scripts` (выдает хтмл-коллекцию). Скажем:

```
setInterval(()=>{
    if (document.scripts.length > 1) {
        alert(`Подключены какие-то левые скрипты: ${[...document.scripts].map(item=>item.src).join(', ')}`);
    };
}, 5000);
```

Comment: document.scripts можно подделать

Comment: А впрочем его даже подделывать не надо: после запуска постороннего скрипта можно просто удалить соответствующий хтмл-элемент из страницы, и из document.scripts он пропадёт тоже

Comment: Не, понятное дело, если код встраивается в недобросовестных целях или реальным человеком, то его можно (и вероятнее всего) не отследить. Если через ту же консоль пойти, например. Но если встраивание идет обычными расширениями, не замороченными на скрытность, то вполне себе можно отследить. я так понял, здесь нужно это

Comment: И да, а как подделать document.scripts?

Comment: Через Object.defineProperty впихнуть какой-нибудь другой HTMLCollection

Comment: Да, действительно. Не подумал

Comment: обычные расширения вообще ничего не внедряют, а работают в песочнице. А если внедряют - это уже необычные расширения и удалить скрипт после инициализации запросто могут. Я например всегда удаляю, что бы на захламлять страницу и случайно не повлиять на ее выполнение (вдруг на самом сайте есть скрипты которые как то ориентируются на <script>)

Comment: Проверил - не определяет этот код посторонний скрипт. Тестировал с помощью касперского - он внедряет свой скрипт в head страницы, но наш код его не видит.

Comment: А на сайте точно есть еще скрипты, кроме внедренного? Этот интервал проверяет, больше ли одного скрипта не странице. Тут нужно ориентироваться на количество собственных скриптов

Comment: О, точно. На странице был включен 1 скрипт, я его вообще убрал + прописал в коде "if (document.scripts.length > 0)". Браузер теперь показывает сообщение, что скрипт подключен, но не выводит его src, т.е. ссылку на скрипт

Comment: А что выводит ?

Comment: А не, это он сам себя видимо определяет на странице, когда значение "if (document.scripts.length > 0)".

Comment: Выводил просто надпись "Подключены какие-то левые скрипты:"

Comment: В общем, этот код не видит инъекции посторонних скриптов на странице

Comment: Если у вас один скрипт - ваш собственный - то, логично, проверка должна быть на количество скриптов, большее единицы. Кроме того, не обязательно проверять количество - можно, например, цеплять к своим скриптам специальный атрибут (`data-script`, скажем), а в интервале проверять, имеет ли каждый скрипт из document.scripts этот атрибут. Так или иначе, перебор коллекции скриптов - самый простой и, вероятно, единственный способ обнаружить какую-то примесь инородного кода на сайте

Comment: В том то и дело, что он не видит посторонний скрипт... И я не знаю почему

Comment: Не могу понять, в чем может быть проблема. Вот такую модификацию кода из моего ответа использую - все прекрасно обнаруживается: https://codepen.io/Vagin/pen/OJNLRZe (единственное, на кодопен он обнаруживает в том числе и кодопеновские скрипты, скрытые в редакторе)

Comment: Проверил ваш код - скрипты, прописанные в коде страницы он видит. А вот скрипт каспера нет. Его кстати видно только в исходном коде страницы, а через меню "проверить элемент" его не видать. Может и скрипт его поэтому не видит. Можете установить касперский free и проверить самостоятельно